# Number of Microstates of Independent Molecules in a Box

Tags: statistical-mechanics

For a volume $V$ and $N$ independent molecules of volume $\delta V$, the number of microstates $\Omega$ is

$$
\Omega=\left(V/\delta V\right)^N.
$$

I'm having trouble understanding why this is the case. If we have $N$ objects and $V/\delta V=X$ cells to put them in, then shouldn't the number of possible microstates/arrangements $\Omega$ be
$$
   \Omega=X(X-1)(X-2)\times\ldots\times(X-N+1)(X-N);
$$

i.e. $^XP_N$ permutations?

Comment: It depends on whether your allow multiple objects to be in the same cell.

Comment: What if $X\gg N$, could the approximation then be made that $\Omega\simeq(V/\delta V)^N$?

Comment: Yes; if the density is sufficiently low you can sometimes neglect excluded volume effects. This is done, for example, when approximating a real gas as an ideal gas.